# Why am I getting a error in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For some reason theres a error somewhere in my parenthises but i cant seem to figure it out can anyone help me. The error starts by the second if statement
somewhere one of my closing brackets or opening brackets is my fault. The if statements is fine though.Thanks in advance

```
                if (series[1].length > 0) {
                    var chart2 = _content.find("#Chart_Pie_2_" + i).get(0);
                    $(chart2).parents(".charts").addClass("double");
                    Chartist.Pie(chart2, {
                        labels: labels[1],
                        series: series[1]
                    }, {
                        fullWidth: true,
                        donut: true,
                        showLabel: false,
                        plugins: [
                            Chartist.plugins.legend(),
                            Chartist.plugins.tooltip({
                                appendToBody: true,
                                tooltipFnc: function (meta) {
                                    return meta;
                                }
                            })
                        ]


                    });

                    if (series[1].length > 0) {
                        var chart3 = _content.find("#Chart_Pie_3_" + i).get(0);
                        $(chart3).parents(".charts").addClass("double");
                        Chartist.Pie(chart3, {
                            labels: labels[2],
                            series: series[2]
                        }, {
                            fullWidth: true,
                            donut: true,
                            showLabel: false,
                            plugins: [
                                Chartist.plugins.legend(),
                                Chartist.plugins.tooltip({
                                    appendToBody: true,
                                    tooltipFnc: function (meta) {
                                        return meta;
                                    }
                                })
                            ]


                        })
                    }
```

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: Get yourself a somewhat useful IDE, which will highlight missing brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

you were missing closing brakcet `}` on first `if`

```
if (series[1].length > 0) {
    var chart2 = _content.find("#Chart_Pie_2_" + i).get(0);
    $(chart2).parents(".charts").addClass("double");
    Chartist.Pie(chart2, {
        labels: labels[1],
        series: series[1]
    }, {
        fullWidth: true,
        donut: true,
        showLabel: false,
        plugins: [
                  Chartist.plugins.legend(),
                  Chartist.plugins.tooltip({
                      appendToBody: true,
                      tooltipFnc: function (meta) {
                          return meta;
                      }
                  })
                  ]


    });
}// this was missing!
    if (series[1].length > 0) {
        var chart3 = _content.find("#Chart_Pie_3_" + i).get(0);
        $(chart3).parents(".charts").addClass("double");
        Chartist.Pie(chart3, {
            labels: labels[2],
            series: series[2]
        }, {
            fullWidth: true,
            donut: true,
            showLabel: false,
            plugins: [
                      Chartist.plugins.legend(),
                      Chartist.plugins.tooltip({
                          appendToBody: true,
                          tooltipFnc: function (meta) {
                              return meta;
                          }
                      })
                      ]


        });
    }
```